# Excel VBA: Is there a faster way to do a running total?

Tags: vba, excel, countif, cumulative-sum

I'm using a countif function with an expanding range and auto-filling to get the running totals and was wondering if there was a better way to go about it.

COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2) + autofill down

There seems to be no problem if there's just a few thousand rows, but when it gets to 10k+ rows it slows down considerably.

I searched online for some clues, but all the "faster" ways had to do with the TOTAL count, not a RUNNING count.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: pivot table maybe?

Comment: Hi Nathan, I did see some stuff on pivot tables, but they were only for total counts, not for a running total. I would need the information for which one is the first instance, which is the second instance, etc.
Is there a way to do this with pivot tables? Could you provide additional details?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Dictionary`, faster on large data because it uses an efficient search algorithm (binary search). On large datasets this should make a noticeable difference.

```
Sub RunningCounts()
  Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim r As Range: Set r = Sheet1.Range("A2", Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp))
  Dim values: values = r.Value2
  Dim i As Long
  For i = LBound(values, 1) To UBound(values, 1)
     dict(values(i, 1)) = dict(values(i, 1)) + 1
     values(i, 1) = dict(values(i, 1))
  Next
  r.Offset(, 1).value = values ' <-- writes results on next column. change as needed
End Sub
```

Comment: @EricJang did you try this, or did you end up with something better?